# Remove large percentage of nodes from shapefile

Tags: qgis

I am trying to reduce the number of nodes in a shapefile because I want to extract the X and Y coordinates for use in R. As the number of nodes approaches hundreds of thousands, it does not work well with what I am doing.

Is there any way to do this with QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. FYI: Generally the points at the *ends* of line segments are referred to as "nodes". Interior points are generally just considered "vertices." You're looking to "generalize" or "simplify" your geometries. Be careful when generalizing polygons, because you may cause slivers of overlap or gaps between neighboring geometries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Simplify Geometries** under **Vector** ==> **Geometry Tools**.  Depending on what value you select for your **Simplify tolerance** and what type of data is in your shapefile, the operation may render your data undesirable for farther analysis. See the effect of the operation in the images below.

[image: Before simplifying]

Before simplifying

[image: After simplifying]

After simplifying